# Wocommerce Attribute Quantity / Packs on Admin Order Details Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have an Woocommerce online store and I want to sell a product in packs of several units.
In other words, it will be a variable product (but all variations will have the same SKU), with the attribute "Pack" in which the variations are, for example: "1 unit", "5 units" and "20 units".

I need a code snippet with these requirements:

1 - When the customer orders a variation whose term is greater than "1", the stock must be reduced by that quantity. For example, if the customer orders the "20 units" variation, 20 units must be removed from stock.

2 - If the customer orders, for example, the "20 units" variation, on the Admin Order Details Page, the number 20 must appear in the "Quantity" column. In other words, 20 units of that SKU will be invoiced and not 1 pack of 20 units. (See the attached image: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/keitufjnlrux4rw5mshe3/attrb.jpg?rlkey=3vwpljni92hfg8mpnvo44tcw2&dl=0).

I have this code that I pasted into functions.php and fulfills the first requirement.

```
// Modify order item quantity based on pack size
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', 'filter_order_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_item_quantity( $quantity, $order, $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_Pack');
    $quantity_units = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term_name);
    if( is_numeric ( $quantity_units ) && $quantity_units != 0 )
        $quantity *= $quantity_units;
    return $quantity;
}
```

​But i don't know how to make the second requirement work.
Can someone help?

I already tried this (for the second requirement), but didn't work:

```
// Display individual quantity in admin order details for pack products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'display_individual_quantity_in_admin_order', 10, 3 );
function display_individual_quantity_in_admin_order( $order_item_data, $item, $order ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_Pack');
    $quantity_units = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term_name);
    if( is_numeric( $quantity_units ) && $quantity_units != 0 ) {
        $order_item_data['quantity'] = $quantity_units;
    }
    return $order_item_data;
}
```

Comment: Update the quantity trough woocommerce_add_cart_item_data where you can check attribute value and multiply with the quantity in case someone purchase 20 units and sets quantity to 2 for example. This way when someone complete order will give you in order items proper quantity and update variation stock quantity.  No need to overcomplicate things.